# Hibernate Criteria API - How to get a list of an object attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have two classes

```
class House {
    String id
    Long size
    Resident resident
}

class Resident {
    String id
    String name
}
```

What I want, is a list of Residents but i need some restrictions for the House. E.q. on the size e.q. > 20 and limit results by 10

The Residents have no references to the House.

I really don't know how to go on with this.

I tried this:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(House.class);
crit.add(Expression.ge("size", 20));
crit.setMaxResults(10);
crit.addOrder(Order.desc("size"));
return crit.list();
```

but i dont know how to get the connection to the Resident

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(House.class);
crit.add(Expression.ge("size", 20));
crit.setMaxResults(10);
crit.addOrder(Order.desc("size"));
crit.setFetchMode("resident", FetchMode.JOIN);
crit.setProjection(Projections.property("resident"));
return crit.list();
```

Answer (score 2):

"The Residents have no references to the House" - AFAIK Hibernate Criteria can't create restrictions on another entry from a given entry when there is no association.

So you can't create a `Criteria` for `Resident.class` and add `Restriction`s there.

What you could try is to create a `Criteria` for your `House.class`, add the required `Restriction`s, and then set a `Projection` to get out your `Resident.class` instances.

What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RAS was kind enough to [provide a working example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13135907/53444) using the above approach and details from your updated question.